# Excel: Count the frequency base on 2 values

Tags: excel, countif

I searched this problem online, and tried this [formula with frequency(if..)](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/236075-counting-using-frequency-formula-multiple-criteria.html).

```
Sheet1
A       | B
ABC123  | 01/01/2015
ABC123  | 02/01/2015
ABC123  | 03/01/2015
BB123   | 01/01/2015

Sheet2
A       | B          | C
ABC123  | 02/01/2015 | Count = 2
BBB123  | 02/02/2015 | Count = 0
```

I want to get the count / frequency of how many times `ABC123` occured on `Sheet1` with a date on or after `02/01/2015`. In this case the answer is three.

```
=sum(if(FREQUENCY(if(CENSUS!A:A='Roster Reconciliation'!A2, if(CENSUS!A:A<>"", CENSUS!A:A), if(CENSUS!B:B>='Roster Reconciliation'!'Roster Reconciliation'!C2, if(CENSUS!B:B<>"", CENSUS!B:B))),1))
```

Currently this does not work, as I might have entered too many arguments.

Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390243/countif-to-give-a-count-of-the-unique-vaules-using-3-criterias/39391940#39391940

Comment: Do you want to count the number of unique dates after the one set or just all the occurrences after that date?  If unique look at the link if all then the answer below will work.

Comment: @ScottCraner I want to count the number of occurrences on/after that date. The ABC123 is like a SSN, and the date is when member enrolled into the program.

Comment: Then you do not need frequency and the answer below should work.

Comment: @ScottCraner How can I set it = A2 instead of hardcode the SSN? and same for the date (reference to the date) instead of putting "02/01/2015".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "ABC123", B:B, ">=02/01/2015")
```

If you want to bind it with a specific cell:

```
=countifs(CENSUS!A:A, A2, CENSUS!B:B, ">=" & C2)
```

Comment: `=countifs(CENSUS!A:A, ='Roster Reconciliation'!A2, CENSUS!B:B, '>=' Roster Reconciliation'!C2)` Does not work when it is a value from a cell?

Comment: You mean like: `=countifs(CENSUS!A:A, A2, CENSUS!B:B, '>=C2')`

Comment: @ScottCraner This fixed it! Thank you!!